# DMV DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY suddenly broken on SSAS Tabular, how to debug/fix?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tabular, dmv

Just started using DMVs on a tabular SSAS instance and after a cube re-work, DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY suddenly stopped working. It now returns an unexpected error.

Swear to god, this used to work : https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6mmH.jpg

Where can I get more information on what's causing the problem?

Is there a repository of the DMVs queries/views/stored proc? Do we know what's going on 'inside' ?

I currently call if from a MSSQL instance, is there a way to run it directly on the SSAS server? Maybe I'd get a proper error message...

Thanks all!

UPDATE : By removing measures and columns from the model, the DMV started working again so there's something fishy with one of my columns. Need to figure out which one...

Comment: I may have found it : can someone validate that DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY doesn't support measures that uses SUMMARIZE ?

Answer (score 0):

When you open SSMS, choose Analysis Services instead of Database Engine to connect to the SSAS instance.  Once connected to the SSAS server, open a new query window (button on the menu or `CTRL + N` when the cube is selected) and run the query directly there.  It will likely open an MDX query editor window, but querying the DMV from this will work fine.  I'd also recommend downloading DAX Studio (link [here](http://daxstudio.org/)), as this will show you all the available DMVs and they can be run directly from here to.

Comment: No dice, still "Unexpected error"..

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Are you still using OPENROWSET?  If so, this isn't necessary.  You can query the DMV just like a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I had the same error with DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY. Through lots of troubleshooting, the problem was in using a temp table in a VAR statement, like this expression:

```
    VAR temptable = FILTER(
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Arrangement[ABN], 
      FILTER(Arrangement, NOT(ISBLANK(Arrangement[ABN]))),
      "active arrangements", [Active arrangement count]),
      [active arrangements] >= 1
    )
    RETURN COUNTROWS(temptable)
```

Changing it to this expression fixed the problem for me:

```
    COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Arrangement[ABN], 
        FILTER(Arrangement, 
        NOT(ISBLANK(Arrangement[ABN]))),
        "active arrangements", [Active arrangement count]),
     [active arrangements] >= 1)))
```